# Regular expression making for android

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression but i am newbie in it. And it seems Like i am failing again and again in this..

Kindly if anyone can help me

Basically what i want an expression that tests for the following,

> 1- Something that starts with abc or def, followed by a number between
>   0 and 900, then can have anything between that, up until the nearest
>   !!

Any help will be regarded

Best Regards

Comment: Can you give an example? What you mean by "then can have anything between that, up until the nearest!!" ?

Comment: Add some example you want to catch. The `then ...` part is hard to understand

Comment: @Yul ignore it, tell me about rest part please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this `abcXXX(0<xxx<900)` or `defXXX (0<xxx<900)` try this:

```
\b(abc)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|900)\b|\b(def)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9[0-9]|900)\b]
```

**Explanation**: The regex `[0-9]` matches single-digit numbers 0 to 9. `[1-9][0-9]` matches double-digit numbers 10 to 99. That's the easy part. So `0-900` is `0-899` and `900` so REGEX is `[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|900` . Add `\b(  )\b` is [Boundary Matchers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html). Similar to `def` : start with `def` followed by 3 digits.

```
\b(def)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|900)\b
```

At last use `|` is `or`.

Tested with [Regular Expression Test Page for Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Maybe i didn't try some weird input but this is the basic parts for you to dig by yourself

Edit with  Alan Moore's nicer suggestion :

```
\b(abc|def)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|900)\b
```

Comment: +1, but yu don't have to repeat the whole regex.   This will do: `\b(abc|def)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-8][0-9][0-9]|900)\b`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match with the first part of your expression. It is hard to understand second part of the expression.

> Something that starts with abc or def, followed by a number between 0
>   and 900

```
^(abc|def)([0-9]{1,2}|[1-8][0-9]{2}|900)
```

I explained the expressions below.

```
^(abc|def)   //Starts with abc or def
(
   [0-9]{1,2}|[1-8][0-9]{2}|900   // matches number between 0-900
)
```